# Get the string from the dictionary in array

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, plist

I use data.plist for populating UITableView. And I need to add cells with titles from String in the Dictionary and in the Array. How can i do it?

```
Root
--Array
-----Dictionary
-------**String**
-------Array2
-----Dictionary
-------**String**
-------Array2
```

I am using this code in viewDidLoad:

```
NSString *path = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Data"
                                                 ofType:@"plist"];

NSDictionary *dictionary = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
_mathArray = [dictionary objectForKey:@"Title"];
```

But it loads String, and String2

```
Root
--Array
-----Dictionary
-------String2
-------Array2
-----Dictionary
-------String2
-------Array2
-----**String**
```

[image]

Comment: I am trying to add cells into UITableView with titles from string in the dictionary

Comment: Show the code for how you're trying to do that then ;-)

Comment: Which array elements and which dictionary keys do you want to use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you can access the plist and is stored in a Dictionary or Array. So I assume you have the data in an Array already.

so in cellForRowAtIndexPath. You get the dictionary out by doing

```
NSDictionary* cellData = [plistArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
[cell.textLabel setText:[cellData objectForKey:@"Title"]];
```

This would set the cell text label to the title in your plist array.

Comment: No problem. More detail next time, had to do a lot of assuming :P